# Socketerror on port 80

Tags: python, macos, bottle

I'm having trouble creating a working executable using PyInstaller. I've been able to successfully create a simple web server using Python and Bottle - but when I create my executable with PyInstaller and click it - I get the following output:

```
Alans-MBP:~ alanscarpa$ /Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/dist/testing ; exit;
Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:80/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/bottle", line 3093, in run
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/bottle", line 2692, in run
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/wsgiref.simple_server", line 151, in make_server
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 420, in __init__
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/wsgiref.simple_server", line 48, in server_bind
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/BaseHTTPServer", line 108, in server_bind
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 434, in server_bind
  File "/Users/alanscarpa/Desktop/testSite/build/testing/out00-PYZ.pyz/socket", line 224, in meth
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
logout

[Process completed]
```

The first 3 lines are perfect - and that's how it should look if working fine:

```
  Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
    Listening on http://0.0.0.0:80/
    Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But then everything after that, messes up my program!

Here's my Python file called testing.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
from bottle import route, run, template


@route('/testing')
def index():
    return 'Hello..testing'

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

When I visit mylocalip/testing - I get webpage unavailable.  But if I open up terminal and write:  sudo /path/to/testing - it works perfectly.  (I obviously want to be able to send the executable to someone and they just click it to run instead of having to use Terminal).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:  I changed my port to 8080 and it's working!  Anyone know why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't listen on ports below 1024 without root privileges on most systems (at least BSD, OS X and Linux).

Comment: thank you for the answer. i was hoping not to have to deal with port numbers. but there is no easy way around it.

Even when i try to execute my script with sudo other problems start happening.